# EAV table, find if 2 records exists simultaneously

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have an EAV table named `keywords`, the keywords belong to a `document` linked by `document_id`.

Now I want to know if there is a document which has 2 keywords, `keywordA` and `keywordB` which determined value.

I made this, but since I'm newbie in SQL (MySQL), I would like to know if there is a better way:

```
select * from 
(select * from keywords k where k.keyword = "Nº de Operacion" and k.value = "000539090279") a, 
(select * from keywords k where k.keyword = "Fecha" and k.value = "20140611") b;
```

Then I check if rows are > 0, or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the records in same query:

```
SELECT Count(*) KeywordCount
FROM   keywords k
WHERE  ( k.keyword = 'Nº de Operacion'
         AND k.value = '000539090279' )
        OR ( k.keyword = 'Fecha'
             AND k.value = '20140611' );
```